# Mysql - query to fetch application name with addition of data

Tags: mysql

I have below table name "data"

---

Application   | Bytes

---

### DNS           | 10

### HTTP          | 10

DNS           | 20
--------------|-------------
TCP           | 30

I want to write a query which can give me one application name with total number of bytes it has consumed (for DNS 10+20 = 30 for ex) something link below table

---

Application   | Bytes

---

### DNS           | 30

### TCP          | 20

HTTP        | 10

Comment: Sure, possible. You use the SUM function together with the GROUP BY clause. Both are well documented, just take a look at the original mysql documentation you can find on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregate function like SUM and group by

```
select Application, Sum(Bytes)
from data
group by Application ;
```